# TWI problem on mega2560

Tags: avr, twi

The TWI on mega2560 seem to be malfunctioning. the below code, believed to be correct as per data sheet, gives a proper start sequence, a proper address and a correct ACK. But when writing and sending data to TWDR and then setting all bits in the TWCR incl TVINT, nothing at all happens. When trying the same startup with read, it works fine up to the point of reading and again - nothing happens. But the STOP condition after the Read is properly performed.
So, what's keeping it from issuing the proper Read/Write sequence?
Including a oscilloscope picture of SCL (top) and SDA (bottom) during Read.
Code:

```
------------- write to PCF8574N extension port -------------

I2CFLAG=false;

/*start*/
TWCR= (1<<TWINT) | (1<<TWSTA) | (1<<TWEN) | (1<<TWIE); 
while(!I2CFLAG);
ta=TWSR;
/*adress+W*/
I2CFLAG=false;
TWDR=0x40;
TWCR= (1<<TWINT) | (1<<TWEA) | (1<<TWEN) | (1<<TWIE); 
while(!I2CFLAG);
tb=TWSR;

/* data out*/
I2CFLAG=false;
TWDR=0x5A;
TWCR= (1<<TWINT) | (1<<TWEA) | (1<<TWEN) | (1<<TWIE);
while(!I2CFLAG);
tc=TWSR;


------------- read from extension port --------------------

I2CFLAG=false;
/*start*/
TWCR= (1<<TWINT) | (1<<TWSTA) | (1<<TWEN) | (1<<TWIE); 
while(!I2CFLAG);
ta=TWSR;

/* set address+R*/
I2CFLAG=false;
TWDR=0x41;
TWCR= (1<<TWINT) | (1<<TWEA) | (1<<TWEN) | (1<<TWIE);
while(!I2CFLAG);
tb=TWSR;

/* get data*/
I2CFLAG=false;
TWCR= (1<<TWINT) | (1<<TWEA) | (1<<TWEN) | (1<<TWIE); 
while(!I2CFLAG);
tc=TWSR;
twdata=TWDR;

/*stop*/
I2CFLAG=false;
TWCR= (1<<TWINT) | (1<<TWSTO) | (1<<TWEN) | (1<<TWIE);
while(!I2CFLAG);
te=TWSR;
tdata1=TWDR;
/* end of process */
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't that a NACK you get in response to the read address (0x41) in the 'scope view?

Answer (score 1):

no, the ACK is a 0 and a NACK is a 1. SDA is lower trace and SCL the upper trace. As yopu can see when SCL goes high, the SDA is low, meaning ACK (since the I2C is passive pullup and thus an active signal is low).